# Does a certified (ISO 26262 or similar) C++ standard library exist?

Tags: c++, stl, iso, safety-critical

While certified C++ toolchains (compiler etc.) exist I did not find any certified C++ standard library (STL).

Does anyone know of someone providing this?

Comment: Certified by whom?

Comment: TUV, exida or some other certification agency.

Comment: So, anyone that says they are a "certification agency"?

Comment: Sure. If you can contribute something, please do so.

Comment: I really don't  understand what you are asking here - these organisations you name have no authority to certify anything. Why do you want a C++ standard library "certified" by such organisations?

Comment: C++ is in an interesting space. Most of the time when I see someone touting safety critical C++, they have removed the ++ by discarding most of the tools that make C++ worth using instead of C in the first place.

Comment: @user4581301: Yes, this is a problem. But we would like to provide a C++ and not a C solution.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: From https://www.tuv-sud.com/industries/automotive-transportation/automotive-solutions/quality-and-safety-services/automotive-functional-safety: 
We are accredited to perform IEC 61508 and ISO 26262 certification for development tools, development processes and safety-relevant products or systems.

Comment: https://www.exida.com/SAEL-Safety/search_results/eyJjb2xsZWN0aW9uIjoiU0FFTF8xNCIsInJlc3VsdF9wYWdlIjoiU0FFTC1TYWZldHlcL3NlYXJjaF9yZXN1bHRzIiwia2V5d29yZHMiOiJ0b29sY2hhaW4ifQ

Comment: @user2100815 - Your probing questions appear to aim at letting the question sound ridiculous - which it isn't by far: The field of functional safety relies on laws and other legal directives (such as Directive 2006/42/EC for machinery in the European Union, similar ones exist in the U.S., Russia, China, etc.). Those laws all require some kind of assessment that must be performed by [notified bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notified_body), which are assigned by the respective authorities. Companies such as the TÜVs in Germany are typical examples for such notified bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Certification demands strict following of ISO26262 and ASPICE standards, which would mean writting all documentation from system to unit level and also tests on all levels, parallel with documentation (see V model in ISO26262). Also, this would demand safety case for STL as "safety element out of context", which would demand inventing assumptions of use for all library parts and creating safety manual for user which will require use of library only in intended way. This would increase development cost for order of magnitude, and then market for this would be non-existent, as using it would demand writing custom memory manager which would allocate memory from statically allocated space, and then analyzing complete application to proof it'll newer need more memory then this preallocated amount, which would be major undertaking, so certified STL could theoretically exist, but mentioned reasons would probably prevent development of one.

Comment: So in short, does it exist or not?

Comment: Not that I know about it.