# Does frama-c satisfy the ISO 26262 standard of the Automotive sector?

Tags: frama-c

The Question arises because we want to apply the frama-C's Plugin "Value Analysis" in this industry.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is a bit broad and borderline here in SO. [A similar question related to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340145/does-a-certified-iso-26262-or-similar-c-standard-library-exist) got several close votes and no answers so far. Maybe you could provide more details about the parts of the standard that would need to be certified, or contact directly the Frama-C team for information concerning industrial applicability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anol, at the end I wrote the frama-c Team because the Question here as you pointed out was a bit generic and unprecise.

Comment: Would you be willing to write an "answer" post containing the information you learned from contacting the `frama-C` team?